# How to pass an array to a function as argument

Tags: php, arrays

I made this code where I define an array, fliepath, in which I store the locations of some files.

```
     include 'last_file.php'; // Include the function last_file
     $last_file = last_file();  // assign to the function a variable and call the  function last_file
    // Connect to the database
     include('connect_thesis.php');

    // Defining an array, which has the three paths to the three different gps receivers
    $file_path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check/".$last_file[0];
    //echo $file_path[0]; echo "<br>";
    $file_path[1] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check2/".$last_file[1];
    //echo $file_path[1]; echo "<br>";
    $file_path[2] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check3/".$last_file[2];
    //echo $file_path[2]; echo "<br>";
```

Then I made a function called insert() which I want to take as input the   $file_path[0]:

```
     function insert($file_path){

     $fh = fopen($file_path,'r') or die ("Could not open:".mysql_error()).......;
```

I call the function from the main script as:

```
         insert($file_path[0]);
```

I am new in programming and I am sure somewhere I am missing something basic!
The problem is that the function doesn't run!!!
Can you help me?
Thanx
D.

I THINK I DONT PASS CORRECTLY THE VALUE TO THE FUNCTION. CAUSE I GET NOTHING AS AN ERROR!

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: So... do you get an error or what?

Comment: How can there be a mysql error here: `$fh = fopen($file_path,'r') or die ("Could not open:".mysql_error()); WTH???`

Comment: I think I don't pass correctly the value to the function. Cause I get nothing as an error.. Does this make sense??

Comment: So whenpeople they don't understand a question, immediately they degrade it. Sorry, but I am trying to learn how to program. And this is the reason this place exists. If you don't understand something then simple don't answer it!

Comment: If you think there are is a problem with the value passed to the function, check it by using `var_dump($your_variable);` before calling the function and inside the function.

Comment: I check it before and I get this: string(51) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check/data_1.txt"

Comment: Should I return something from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points to note:

You are calling insert using only the index 0, consider using a foreach and call the function on each items in your array.

insert() -> we are missing part of the implementation, but if the file exists, you should not get an error.  Keep in mind that you need to close files that you open.

or die -> it looks like you copy pasted code from elsewhere... mysql_error() will not help you much as you're dealing with files at the moment. Consider changing it to

```
$fh = fopen($file_path,'r') or die ("Could not open:".$file_path)
```

You should probably handle graciously the error instead of using "die"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It's true that I don't include the whole insert function in the question cause it is 64 lines and I think it is irrelevant to the problem. I do close the file in the end of my function. Also, I don't want to use the foreach cause I specifically want as an input of the function only the first element of the array!

Comment: Ok, then would you care telling us what is wrong with your code?  How do you know it doesn't get executed?  Have you tried printing something inside of it? (use echo)

Comment: Well I couldn't access the function and I didn't know what is the problem. Now I can access it cause I added this to the main script: include('insert.php')

Comment: Now that you can access the function, is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
function insert($file_path) {
    foreach ($file_path as $file) {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my problem is that I make some mistake when I pass the value to the function. insert($file_path[0]);